# Swapping ViewControllers of NavigationController while maintaining same navbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have implemented a slide out menu with some tinkering from this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/299-how-to-create-your-own-slide-out-navigation-panel-in-swift)

The slide out works fine, but where I'd like my functionality to differ is when a menu option is clicked, I'd like the view on the main screen to be swapped out for another totally different view. When I swap views, I'd like to maintain the navigation bar the same because I want users to be able to continually open the slide-out menu from whatever view they are on.

What currently happens: Slide out menu works fine, but when I click on a new menu option, the view appears, but I lose the navigation bar with a left button that is supposed to allow for re-opening slide-out menu.

What currently happens. As soon as "favorites" clicked, the page displays, but left navigation button is lost (along with that functionality).

[image]

**Here is how I set my code up**

I have a ContainerViewController where I set up all these views:

```
var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
let favoritesViewController = FavoritesViewController()
let settingsViewController = SettingsViewController()
let supportViewController = SupportViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainWhite()

    setupNavigation()
    setupGestureRecognizers()
}

fileprivate func setupNavigation() {

    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)

    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)

    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)
    centerNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    setupLeftBarButtonItem()

    centerNavigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .mainGreen()
    centerNavigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .mainGreen()
    centerNavigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

//Handle showing new ViewControllers...
func didSelectMenuOption(type: MenuSelection) {

    switch type {

    case .home:
        print("home...")
    case .favorites:
        print("favorites...")
        centerNavigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
        centerNavigationController.pushViewController(favoritesViewController, animated: false)
    case .settings:
        print("settings...")
        centerNavigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
        centerNavigationController.pushViewController(settingsViewController, animated: false)
    case .support:
        centerNavigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
        centerNavigationController.pushViewController(supportViewController, animated: false)
        print("support...")
    case .logout:
        print("logging out...")


}
```

Ideally, I'd like to just "swap" out my VC's and keep that same NavBar. Is there a way to say, set the VC's in my navigation controller and then do something like this?

Comment: You will need to set left navigationItem property on viewController when you are pushing. `viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...`. **OR** implement the delegate `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` and set the leftBarButtonItem property on the viewController in here.

Comment: @ntsh ok that makes sense.. but in terms of replacing the VC's is this way the best way? Should I be popping VC's and pushing versus using some other way of just moving between View Controllers?

Comment: `centerNavigationController.viewControllers = @[favoritesViewController]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UINavigationController's navbar shows the buttons set by the viewController that is being displayed, so you will need to set the leftBarButtonItem when changing your viewControllers.

```
case .favorites:
    print("favorites...")

    favoritesViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ... // Set UIBarButtonItem 

    centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [favoritesViewController]
```

You could also implement the delegate method `navigationController(_:willShow:animated:)` and set the leftBarButtonItem property  on the viewController:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, 
                         willShow viewController: UIViewController, 
                                        animated: Bool) {

     viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ... // Set UIBarButtonItem
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. This worked. Great solution. Just remove the '@' from your answer its a typo.

Comment: @mufc Good catch. I mixed the objective-c syntax.